# Azure DevOps: The resource type 'microsoft.visualstudio/account' is not supported in the preview experience

Tags: azure-devops

I get the error below in Azure DevOps: 
"The resource type 'microsoft.visualstudio/account' is not supported in the preview experience."
Session ID ac229aeef9f54640a62cc1e9f1aef13d
Extension HubsExtension
Error code ---

Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you express more about your operation? Such as which page are you accessing? And did you install any customized extension in it? Which preview feature are you enabled? Better share some screenshots:-)

Comment: I am getting same error , some resources are trying to open in "preview mode"